# Django Model design help for three relational tables

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have 3 tables in the sql database. I need to create django models for these.

```
table1: Module

|modulename |moduleversion  |notes      |
-----------------------------------------
|M1         |1              |module 1   |
|M2         |2              |module 2   |
|M3         |1              |module 3   |
|M4         |1              |module 4   |
|M5         |3              |module 5   |
-----------------------------------------
table2: metamodule

|metamodulename |metaversion    |modulename |
---------------------------------------------
|A              |1              |M1         |
|B              |2              |M1         |
|C              |1              |M3         |
|A              |1              |M4         |
|B              |2              |M2         |
---------------------------------------------

table3: release

|releasenumber  |notes      |metamodules|
-----------------------------------------
|R1             |Rel ver 1  |A          |
|R1             |Rel ver 1  |B          |
|R2             |Rel ver 2  |A          |
|R2             |Rel ver 2  |C          |
|R3             |Rel ver 3  |C          |
-----------------------------------------
```

These tables are having foreign key constraints. I am confused which relationship model to be used for creating the models for the above tables.

Solution:

```
from django.db import models 

class module(models.Model):
    modulename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    moduleversion = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.modulename)


class metamodule(models.Model):
    metamodulenname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    metaversion = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    modulename = models.Foreignkey(module)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.metamodulename)


class release(models.Model):
    releasenumber = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    metamodules = models.ManytoMany(metamodule)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.releasenumber)
```

Here i have thought of a solution.
Please put down your suggestions and solutions to correct my solution

Answer (score 1):

This mostly looks correct, but `release.metmodules` should be a `ForeignKey`, not a `ManyToManyField`. When you declare a `ManyToManyField`, Django creates a new table behind the scenes to hold the relationship between the two tables.

In your case that means that `release` would contain only the `releasenumber` and `notes` fields, and there would be a fourth table for holding the relationship between `metamodule` and `release`. To match the structure you showed, just use a `ForeignKey`.

Another thing to think about is whether there are any other constraints on the data.

- Is `modulename` unique? Then add `unique=True`.
- Is the combination of `metamodulename` and `modulename` unique in the `metamodule` table? If so, use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).
- Similarly with `metamodules` and `releasenumber`.

I also agree with @Alp's comments on naming.

Comment: As the records are returning multiple records i used ManyToManyField for Release.metamodules. I am importing a csv file to the ManyToManyField in Release, I am getting the below error.             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 416, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'metamodules' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @user3818325: Well, like I said, you can't use a `ManyToManyField` there if your tables are structured in the way you describe. If you do, there will be no `metamodules` field in your table. Django instead has to create a whole new table to hold that relationship.

Comment: @ Kevin Christopher Henry: Ok. If i am using ForeignKey, during csv file import it is returning more than 1 record and i am not able to import the data to the field. How can i handle multiple records import to this field?

Comment: I tried using ForeignKey and i havethe below error.                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 4                             04, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.p                             y", line 405, in __set__
    self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "[]": "Release.metamodules" must be a "Metamodule" instance.

Comment: @user3818325: I'm not sure I understand you. In your sample data above you have a single `metamodules` value for each line of `table 3`. Are you saying that there are in fact multiple values for that field for each line? If so, you will need a `ManyToMany` field, but you have to create the record in a multi-step process. You first create the `release` record and then `add` the existing `metamodules` to it. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) will make clear how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Always use uppercase words for your models: `Module`, `MetaModule` and `Release`. This is best practice by convention.
2. Foreign keys are using the model id per default. Therefore you should name your related columns like the model itself. In `MetaModule`, you should rename `modulename` to `module`.
3. You don't need over-descriptive names for the columns. `Module.modulename` is redundant information. `Module.name` is sufficient and more readable. Same applies to attributes like `moduleversion` (`version`) or `releasenumber` (`number`).

Comment: Okay thanks. Any more suggestions for the solution i have written? Is that correct?